# How to use regular expression extract the number inside the ()?

Tags: regex

Here is example text...

```
ss(12a)eee
ss(121112322)eeede223
```

I would like to extract "121112322" ... ... I can extract the "(121112322)", using this

```
\(\d*\)
```

But I would like to exclude the "()", and the text must inside the (), how can I do so? Thank you.

Comment: For future reference, could you please be more specific about the regular expression implementation?  Which library or language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions provide ways to capture buffers. Check [this](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Capture-buffers) document on how to capture buffers with Perl, which is pretty universal.

Basically, you need to wrap up the piece of regex you want to capture in unescaped parenthesis:

```
(\(\d*\))
```

By convention, in buffer 0 you'll have the whole string, and in buffer 1 you'll have the first captured buffer.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
\((.*)\)
```

The first group will be the value inside the brakets -- an example of usage in javascript

```
var test = 'sfsfsdfsdf(12a)sdfsdfsdf';
var r = test.match(/\((.*)\)/)
console.log(r[1]) // <--- bracket inners
```

and to see it in action

http://jsfiddle.net/tAm2d/